# Cheap Travel (466A) Problem from Codeforces

Tags: c++

**Full problem:** (from https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/466/A)

Ann has recently started commuting by subway. We know that a one ride subway ticket costs a rubles. Besides, Ann found out that she can buy a special ticket for m rides (she can buy it several times). It costs b rubles. Ann did the math; she will need to use subway n times. Help Ann, tell her what is the minimum sum of money she will have to spend to make n rides?

**Input**
The single line contains four space-separated integers n, m, a, b (1 ≤ n, m, a, b ≤ 1000) — the number of rides Ann has planned, the number of rides covered by the m ride ticket, the price of a one ride ticket and the price of an m ride ticket.

**Output**
Print a single integer — the minimum sum in rubles that Ann will need to spend.

Solution from Codeforces (https://codeforces.com/contest/466/submission/7784793):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
 
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    int n, m, a, b;
    
    cin >> n >> m >> a >> b;
    if (m * a <= b)
        cout << n * a << "\n";
    else 
        cout << (n/m) * b + min((n%m) * a, b) << "\n";
 
    return 0;
}
```

Although I understand that the conditional statements check if there should be a special ride ticket bought or not, but how is the expression `(m * a <= b)`  derived, and how it is useful in checking if there should be special tickets bought or not? Additionally, i understand how `(n/m) * b)` is derived, but `min((n%m) * a, b)` really confuses me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (m * a <= b)` covers the nonsensical case (in the real world) where the special ticket is at least as expensive as regular tickets for the same number of journeys. Eg a=1, b=10, m=5. Here `m * a <= b` so it's cheaper to buy the regular tickets.

Having established that it might be worthwhile to buy the regular tickets you should buy `(n/m)` of them at a cost of `(n/m) * b` rubles. The remaining journeys could be paid for with one special ticket costing `b` rubles or with `(n%m)` regular tickets costing `(n%m) * a` rubles. Whichever of those is cheaper gives the formula `min((n%m) * a, b)`.